# How can i check if image file exists on smarty using URL?

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3, smarty2

I want to check if the webp image is exists on the server on `smarty`. The `URL` is an absolute `URL` like [this](https://example.com/image.webp).

i tried

```
{if file_exists("https://example.com/image.webp")}
{/if}
```

and

```
{if 'https://example.com/image.webp'}

{/if}
```

But none is working. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Why don't you do this check in your controller? 
You cannot use file_exists() on a URL, but you can use it on a local file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, you should do something like:

`if (file_exists($filename))`

You could also do this in the view as you're trying to do now, but it's recommended to keep your logic separated from your view.

Don't forget to add the absolute path to the `$filename` variable.

**Edit**:

In case of smarty, you can do the following in your php script:

```
    $smarty = new Smarty();
    
    $fileExist = false;
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
      $fileExists = true;
    }

    $smarty->assign('fileExists', $fileExists);
    
    $smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

In the view/template, you can then simply do:

```
{if $fileExists}
```

Comment: Can u pls suggest what code it will write on controller?

Comment: @MuntashirAreRahi I've edited my answer. Does this answer your question? If it doesn't, please show me your current php and .tpl file, so that I can elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

In smarty, you cannot use `file_exists()` on a URL, but you can use it on a local file

I think, the best way is to check in your controller.

**1st method:**

In your controller, you can write something like that (path only):
https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.file-exists.php

```
$filename = '/example.com/image.webp'
if(!file_exist($filename))
    $filename = '/example.com/other_image.webp'
```

Then return the variable `$filename`

**Other way :**

If you want to check that the image exists from a URL then you should use this:

```
$file = 'http://www.example.com/somefile.jpg';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}
```

then `//do something...`

Comment: You can move @Skyd code to smarty modifier or function to use it directly in template.

Answer (score 0):

You Have To Check File IN
file_exists("var/www/html/example.com/image.webp")
it will note Check Http or Https